# codeigniter validation not working in bootsrap modal window

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the validation class working in codeigniter within a bootstrap modal window. However the function in the controller that contains the codes is not being seen by the form-open function.

This is the modal form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo validation_errors();?>
        <?php echo form_open('Site/login_validation');?>
        <form>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          </div></br>
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
            <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div></br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
          </br>
        </form>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" >Forgot your password</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the form in the controller:

```
public function login_validation(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $this->load->view('view_index');
    }else {
        redirect('Site/view_member');               
    }
}
```

Comment: You're duplicating the <form>tag by opening it once with form_open() and then again on the next line with your HTML. Whatever else is going on, I know hate not right.

Answer (score 0):

As jcorry pointed out, you're duplicating the `<form>` and `</form>` tags. If you're using `form_open()` and `form_close()`, you don't need to include them in your view html.

From the [Codeigniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html):

> form_open() Creates an opening form tag with a base URL built from your config preferences
>
> form_close() Produces a closing  tag.

I suspect the incorrect nesting is confusing your browser, which is trying to close the tags itself. If you View Source you might see something like:

```
<form action="Site/login_validation">
</form><!-- This closing tag added automatically by your browser -->
<form>
    <!-- your form fields ... -->
</form>
</form>
```

The second `<form>` element, which contains your fields, has no action, so it isn't talking to your controller when you hit submit. Delete the `<form>` and `</form>` in your HTML and let us know how that goes.